# Make a variable static after multiple submissions of requests in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, static, controller

I tried to declare a static and public variable in AppController as follows

```
class AppController extends Controller {


public static $var = 0;

}
```

And then access the static variable in controller of its subclass.

My CTP file has multiple submit buttons which change the value of the static variable.

eg.

```
button A -> $var ++  
button B -> $var --
```

I also tried session and started it in beforefilter function of app controller. 
Still on multiple submission, the session variable is reset again.

```
class AppController extends Controller {


public function beforeFilter() {
parent::beforeFilter();
$this->Session->write('var', 0);

}
}
```

In both cases(either static variable or session), the static variable can only be +1, 0 or -1. It seems the AppController is loaded on refresh of page.
What I really want is the static variable can be + or - more than 1 after the buttons are pressed multiple times and the static variable is only reset after close of the browser.

Comment: Sounds like you need to store it in a session, not as a class variable

Comment: If you want to use that static variable then use in it's specific controller (based on ctp) not in `AppController`. 2. best to create a Session variable and update it accordingly.

Comment: I tried session and started it in app controller. Still on refresh, the session variable is reset again.

Comment: Looks to me like you are resetting your session variable every time. if you need it to exist, but don't want to overwrite it every time you can do an if(!$this->Session->get('var')) { $this->Session->write('var', 0); } That way it only creates it the first time, but after that it leaves it alone. Sessions should work just fine for this.

Comment: Yeah! Finally got it. Thanks, Asperon! but $this->Session->get('var') cause fatal error in CakePHP. Dunno y.   Error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ErrorHandler::handleException() must be an instance of Exception

Comment: is that cake2 or cake3?

Comment: It is Cake2. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting the value **when you want, by buttons**, you should use post method in some `controller action` not in `beforeFilter()`.

example:

```
public function foo() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // get posted value from $this->request
        $this->Session->write('var', 'value');
    }
}
```

then you can read the value in any controller like this:

```
$value = $this->Session->read('var');
```

Comment: Though my problem is solved, I would like to know where to create a static variable such that I can add or minus more than 1 in cakePHP instead of using  if(static var or session var not exist) { set value or create session); Thank you anyway

Comment: Static variable don’t keep the value it had on last request. On next request it’ll be set again, as you already know.

Comment: So session is the only way to go? Thanks!

Comment: There could be more ways but I'll use session for this purpose.